# Pythonic way to iterate over multiple queries (and avoid bloating my code)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested-loops

I have the following code block:

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd

cert_path = 'C:\\cert.crt'

start_date = '2020-10-01'
end_date = '2020-10-31'

a_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-A.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

b_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-B.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

c_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-C.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)



query_1 = 'project = \"Test Project 1\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_2 = 'project = \"Test Project 2\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_3 = 'project = \"Test Project 3\" and issuetype = Defect and resolution = Resolved and releasedate >= {} and releasedate <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_4 = 'project = \"Test Project 4\" and issuetype = Enhancement and resolution = Done and completed >= {} and completed <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

block_size = 100
block_num = 0

all_issues = []
while True:
    start = block_num * block_size
    issues = a_session.search_issues(query_1, start, block_size)
    if len(issues) == 0:
        break
    block_num += 1
    for issue in issues:
        all_issues.append(issue)

issues = pd.DataFrame()

for issue in all_issues:
    d = {
        'key' : issue.key,
        'type' : issue.fields.type,
        'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
        'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
    }

    issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

This code runs fine and allows me to:

1. retrieve data associated with only `query_1` (which connects to `a_session`)
2. save that data into a Pandas dataframe

Now, I would like to be able to:

a.  retrieve the data associated with `query_2` (which also onnects to `a_session`) and save it to the `issues` dataframe

b.  retrieve the data associated with `query_3` (which connects to `b_session`) and save it to the `issues` dataframe

c.  retrieve the data associated with `query_4` (which connects to `c_session`) and save it to the `issues` dataframe

**Notice that the structure of `query_3` and `query_4` is different than that of `query_1` and `query_2` (the field names are different, among other things).**

I could write one GIANT script (which would probably work).  But, I'm sure there is a more elegant way of approaching this (perhaps with a nested loop).

What's the best way of adapting this code block such that it treats cases a, b, and c above?

Any help would be much appreciated by this Python novice!  Thanks in advance!

---

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I used the (very elegant) solution suggested by `@Nick ODell`.  The code runs fine, but for whatever reason, I get a `None` result.  I spent the past few hours trying to debug this and my leading theory is that the field names are not passed (as they are in `d` in the original code block I posted).

I tried to amend the `get_all_issues` function as follows:

```
def get_all_issues(session, query):
    start = 0
    all_issues = []
    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size)
        if len(issues) == 0:
            # No more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame

    for issue in all_issues:
        d = {
            'key' : issue.key,
            'type' : issue.fields.type,
            'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
            'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
             }

    issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

But, now there is an error message saying:

```
ValueError:  All objects passed were None.
```

How would we amend the `get_all_issues()` function such that we can nest the following for loop and pass in the name fields, as follows?

```
for issue in all_issues:
    d = {
        'key' : issue.key,
        'type' : issue.fields.type,
        'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
        'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
    }

    issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

---

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Instead of using `pd.json_normalize(issues)`, I used pd.DataFrame(issues) and added a dictionary of field names.  The following code works ** because all fields exist in `a_session`, `b_session`, and `c_session`**:

```
def get_all_issues(session, query):

    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0
    
    start = 0
    all_issues = []
    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size)
        if len(issues) == 0:
            # No more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:
        d = {
            'key' : issue.key,
            'type' : issue.fields.type,
            'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
            'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
             }

        issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    return issues
```

Then, I added 3 new custom fields to the dictionary:

```
    for issue in all_issues:
        d = {
            'key' : issue.key,
            'type' : issue.fields.type,
            'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
            'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution,
            'system_change' : issue.fields.customfield_123,
            'system_resources' : issue.fields.customfield_456,
            'system_backup' : issue.fields.customfield_789
             }
```

Custom field 123 exists in `a_session` and `b_session`, but not in `c_session`.  Custom field 456 exists only in `c_session`. And, custom field 789 exists in `b_session` and `c_session`.

Doing so results in the following error:  `AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'customfield_123'`.

Can anyone suggest an elegant solution to handle this?  (i.e. the ability to have a dictionary with any number of fields, and the code 'understands' which fields relate to a given session)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach your problem. I don't have a Jira instance to test against, so this code is untested.

First, define a function to fetch all issues from a given session for a given query:

```py
def get_all_issues(session, query):
    start = 0
    all_issues = []
    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size)
        if len(issues) == 0:
            # No more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)
    # Flatten JSON
    # This idea is from
    # https://levelup.gitconnected.com/jira-api-with-python-and-pandas-c1226fd41219
    return pd.json_normalize(issues)
```

Next, I would make a list of queries, and the corresponding backend.

```py
queries = [
    (a_session, query_1),
    (a_session, query_2),
    (b_session, query_3),
    (c_session, query_4),
]
```

Next, I would loop over each pair of session and query, calling the function I just defined, and save the dataframe I get each time.

```py
dataframes = []

for session, query in queries:
    dataframe = get_all_issues(session, query)
    dataframes.append(dataframe)
```

Now, the field names for each of these dataframes won't be the same. However, Pandas is actually tolerant to this, and if a column is present in one dataset but not in another, Pandas will fill in the missing column with NaN values. So, just concatenate the rows from each dataframe together:

```py
all = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

... and that's it!

Comment: For whatever reason, using the approach suggested by @Nick ODell results in an empty set.  My leading theory is that the field names are not passed (hence the `None` result).  How would we use `pd.DataFrame` instead of `pd.json_normalize` and pass the field names (as I've done above)?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @equanimity Not sure. I can't actually test this code, so it's hard for me to say what might be wrong. Could you give me a copy of the contents of the `issues` variable? e.g. `print(repr(issues))` (Assuming that you're allowed to post it.)

Comment: when I `print(repr(issues))`, I get:  `Name Error:  name 'issues' is not defined`.  I have the code working, but without using `pd.json_normalize(issues)`.  Now, the problem I'm facing is that some fields exist in certain sessions, but not in others.  I'll post another update above.

Comment: I see you changed `issues` to `all_issues` in your version of the code. Therefore, can you post the contents of `print(repr(all_issues))`?

Comment: when I print(repr(all_issues)), I get: Name Error:  name 'all_issues' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making separate variables for the queries, put them in a list:

```
queries = [
    'query 1 here...',
    'query 2 here...',
]
```

And then iterate over the list:

```
for query in queries:
    process(query)
```

Comment: How would I deal with the fact that 3 of the 4 queries reference different `<x>_session` variables?